# Compiling against a higher version of assemblies but binding redirect to lower versions in app.config

Tags: c#, assembly-binding-redirect

I am compiling my DLLs against a third party strong named assembly (`thirdparty.dll`) with version `2.0.0.0`.

But, when I ship my DLLs and exes to client's machine, I want to ship `thirdparty.dll` version `1.0.0.0` ( don't ask why, I have a reason to do that).

Is this possible? My understanding is that yes, as long as I [specify the `dependentAssembly` tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element?redirectedfrom=MSDN) as such

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="thirdparty" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="3d67ed1f87d44c89"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Because for `newVersion` ,

> This value can specify an earlier version than oldVersion.

The code will work, barring any compilation issues that arise when/if I compile the code against `thirdparty.dll` version `1.0.0.0`.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: YES, it is correct.

EG:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="thirdparty" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="3d67ed1f87d44c89"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

will work ( all the versions between `0.0.0.0` and `2.0.0.0` will be redirected to `1.0.0.0`), and so will:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="thirdparty" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="3d67ed1f87d44c89"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

all the versions between `0.0.0.0` and `2.0.0.0` will be redirected to `4.0.0.0`